# How to make the footer move with content CSS - No floating, all block/inline-block

Tags: html, css

Trying to make my first properly responsive site with a footer that remains offscreen untill scrolled to, then also notices content from above and moves with it. I have a site that does a similar thing but uses all sorts of horrible positioning/floating which i dont want on this one.

I have used all blocks/inline-blocks as its just going to be a basic portfolio sort of site. Here is a JSFiddle showing the problem, if you remove the divs called picture the footer remains in place.

http://jsfiddle.net/41s5vcu8/3/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: "Raleway";
}
#head {
    height: 30%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #DBB84D;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
#content {
    height: 70%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ececec;
}
#gallery_wrap {
     max-width: 1200px;
     height:100%;
     width: 100%;
     margin: auto;
     box-shadow: 0 0 150px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
 }
#picture {
     height:250px;
     width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
     background-color: #fff;
     margin: auto;
}
#foot {
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #676767;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
```

There is some of the CSS, as i cant just post a JSFiddle. I have looked about for some advice but most things talk about sticky footers or using floats and what not. I have tried everythingi can think of and i just cant get it to move with the content....

Or if you know of a question that has already been answered for this that woul dbe great! I have loads of different @media's in this but i slimmed it down to make it less painful for you all.

Comment: You have a defined height for the content ... 70% so the footer will be always there.If your point is to change the behavior after scroll you will need JS

Comment: Give `overflow: auto` to content as it has got height fixed.

Comment: Genius!! I have looked it over so many times and missed that. Setting it to min-height: 70%, instead, fixes it haha.. wow. Pain over, thanks. @Danko

Comment: Jajaaj Np mate glad to help U find the problem :P ... you can delete this question if it is solved now or if you want self-answer your post :)

Comment: Self answer just so others may find the information useful, and wont make my mistake! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out i have looked at this too much and missed a basic thing...

```
#content {
    min-height: 70%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ececec;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/41s5vcu8/5/